# MySql is returning only one row while fetching data form wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have seen many similar questions But they all are confusing for me because I am not using $wpdb variable to fetch data. I am using simple php way to fetch data By calling wordpress database. But somehow its returning only one row. here is the lines of code which are being used to fetch data.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM   teacher_directory";
if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){   
    echo "<table>";
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th>S. No.</th>";
            echo "<th>Name</th>";
            echo "<th>Designation</th>";
            echo "<th>Department</th>";
            echo "<th>Tele/Mob.No.</th>";
        echo "</tr>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['S. No.'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Designation'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Department'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Tele/Mob.No.'] . "</td>";               
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

Any help or suggestion will be appreciable.

Comment: are you getting multiple fields in actual query ?

Comment: What is the result of mysqli_num_rows($result)

Comment: I am getting a complete single row in output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this wordpress query fetch results from database

```
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM teacher_directory WHERE 1', ARRAY_A  );
if(!empty($results)){
  echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>S. No.</th>";
        echo "<th>Name</th>";
        echo "<th>Designation</th>";
        echo "<th>Department</th>";
        echo "<th>Tele/Mob.No.</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
  foreach($results as $row){
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['S. No.'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Designation'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Department'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Tele/Mob.No.'] . "</td>";               
    echo "</tr>";
  }
    echo "</table>"; 
}
```

Comment: It is also returning the single line.

Comment: Hi Rishabh , yo have to declare your database column name in `$row["title"]`.

If i am using `wp_posts` table then I have to declare `$row["post_title"]` where `post_title` is the column name in database.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the $wpdb class (which has functions for directly accessing and manipulating the wordpress database):

```
global $wpdb;
$sql = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM   teacher_directory" );
$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 
if($results) {
echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>S. No.</th>";
        echo "<th>Name</th>";
        echo "<th>Designation</th>";
        echo "<th>Department</th>";
        echo "<th>Tele/Mob.No.</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
foreach( $results as $row ) {
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['S. No.'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Designation'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Department'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Tele/Mob.No.'] . "</td>";               
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: expects parameter warnings on wp-db.php. nothing displays.